# trying to install/use php on a mac

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm trying to set up php on my mac. From what I gathered, mac already comes preinstalled with php so I went through the whole httpd.conf and editing LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so to uncomment it.

I can't find a clear instruction on what to do after that. PHP seems to be still not running when I open a test file in my browser. Some sites say to add a IfModule php5_module block? but others don't mention that.

Comment: What method are you using to open the PHP file in your browser? Have you restarted Apache? (TBH, I generally just give up on Mac Apache and run my development environment in a VM running Debian or Ubuntu).

Comment: I've restarted Apache. Is there a specific way to open PHP file? I just open it like I would a html file.

Comment: By "like I would a html file" do you mean you are double clicking on the icon in Finder?

Comment: basically. Well I click file>open in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

> Well I click file>open in chrome

You are ignoring your web server and loading the file directly from your file system.

This means that Apache will not see the file, so it will not pass it through the PHP engine.

You must load the file over HTTP from your web server. Type `http://localhost/etc/etc` into the address bar (where `/etc/etc` is the path to your file from the `DocumentRoot`).

Answer (score 0):

I use MAMP on a mac to do testing with serverside code - http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/